# Converting .docx,.pptx to .doc,.ppt files online

Tags: microsoft-office, file-conversion

I do not have the latest version of Microsoft Office and because of that I am not able to view a few files I download from the net or which my colleges send me. While, downloading OpenOffice or LibreOffice is always an option. I was wondering if there is any online tool that can convert your .pptx,.docx files into .ppt,.doc files?

NOTE: Kindly do not mention Google Docs, as it afftects the formatting of the document to an extremely large extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these two websites to convert `.doc`x to `.doc` and `.pptx` to `.ppt` online:

- [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/)
- [oConvert](http://oconvert.com/)

It's a good solution if you need to convert a file or two from time to time. Otherwise I suggest you install an application so you'll be able to convert multiple files faster, or use Office (as explained in the other answers) to do the converting.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what version of Office you are running, but the Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack may be your answer.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3

Says it works with Office 2000, XP, and Office 2003.  It simply allows these older versions to open, edit, and save the new formats.

I know it's not online, but you may not need to go online to solve the problem.

Comment: This is a good suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

You might look at the [Office 2013 Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/office/preview/en) (It should have an online, web-based version of Word/Excel/Powerpoint), which should be free for the time being until it's released / the preview ends, and in the future will allow you to use MS Office applications online if you've purchased office. Due to the proprietary nature of MS document formats, I doubt you'll get accurate reproduction of them in anything other than office. For offline tools, OpenOffice and LibreOffice are your best bet, and I'd recommend downloading one or the other if you're against purchasing MS Office and need as accurate reproduction of layouts as you can get. I've not tried the Office 2013 preview yet, but I hope they have accurate reproduction of the documents online. Otherwise, I think gdocs is as good as it gets, as terrible as it is at opening MS-formatted documents.